# Сохранить динамический созданный html как шорткод Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

Привет ребят, есть у меня визуальный редактор, который работает с шорткодами, с этим все нормально, работает как нужно, но у меня появилась идея относительно работы редактора, и соотвественно отсюда вытек вопрос, могу ли я сгенерировать контент в шорткоде динамически? Подразумеваю, что человек добавил в DOM произвольный див (на стороне моего визуального редактора, через append / insertAfter) с заранее имеющимися атрибутами, могу ли я передать этот созданный див в разметку шорткода? или это физически нереально?

js функционал добавления див в DOM есть, интересует именно как можно написать конструкцию самого шорткода, чтобы он прочитал динамически добавленный див